# Get response body on 400 HTTP response in Android?

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I'm communicating with an API that I can not change that sends a 400 response when a request is not validated on the API side.  It is a valid HTTP request, but the request data does not pass the application's validation rules.

The 400 response contains a JSON payload that has information on why the request did not pass validation.

I can't seem to get the response body because an HttpRequestException is thrown.  Does anybody know how to retrieve this response body?

```
try {
        HttpUriRequest request = params[0];
        HttpResponse serverResponse = mClient.execute(request);

        BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = handler.handleResponse(serverResponse);
        return response;
    } catch(HttpResponseException e) {
        // Threw HttpError
        Log.d(TAG, "HttpResponseException : " + e.getMessage());
        Log.d(TAG, "Status Code : " + e.getStatusCode());
        // TODO API returns 400 on successful HTTP payload, but invalid user data
        if(e.getStatusCode() == 400) {
                // Information on API error inside Response body
            }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I send and get Http response as an `byte[]`.Of course you can change it to string if you want.

```
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.rpc.booom.com");



                postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("debug_data","1"));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_api_ver", "1.0.0.0"));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_identificator", deviceId));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_resolution", resolution));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username_hash", hashUser(username,password)));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_hash", hashPass(username,password)));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Log.w("Response ","Status line : "+ response.getStatusLine().toString());
                buffer = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()).getBytes();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for also providing how to get the HTTP status code.  Cheers

Comment: @Andy Lawton, I don't get it, you could just do `byte[] data = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());`! See my updated post.

Comment: @Android-Droid, `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()).getBytes();` is not an effective way of getting byte arrays since you're "assuming" there is the encoding is standard for all data. Rather use, `EntityUtils.toByteArray()` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this, using `org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils`:

```
HttpRequestBase base = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(base);
String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

PS: This is blind coding as I don't know what you tried yet.

To get status code:

```
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

To get the entity body in byte array:

```
byte[] data = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: Thanks! BasicResponseHandler was throwing the HttpException error...EntityUtils lets me get the response body regardless of HTTP status code.

Answer (score 2):

Try that way:

```
if (this.responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
 inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getInputStream();
} else {
inputStream = httpUrlConnection.getErrorStream();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, `getErrorStream()` is your friend in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
                     if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                     StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                     for (String line; (line = r.readLine()) != null; ) {
                         total.append(line).append('\n');
                     }
                     Log.e("temp", String.valueOf(total));

                 }
                 else {
                     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getErrorStream());
                     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                     StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                     for (String line; (line = r.readLine()) != null; ) {
                         total.append(line).append('\n');
                     }
                     Log.e("temp", String.valueOf(total));

                 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).